# Creation of a new dataframe based on other dataframe's columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm trying to create a new data frame from existent data frames:

My new data frame (`new_dataframe`) will contain monthly purchased quantities of a specific year (2017) of two specific categories (c1 and c2). Knowing that, my other data frames are:

- df1 = client_data (clientId, city, category)
- df2 = purchase_data (clientId, quantity, price, purchase_date)

I've tried with `substract()` and `aggregate()` but it didn't work for me.
For instance to get data of the specific year (just a part of the solution), I used this code:

```
new_dataframe <- subset(
  AllInfosClients, 
  AllInfosClients$Date_achat == as.Date(AllInfosClients$Date_acha,"%d/%m/2017")
)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This could have many error sources. I think it would be helpful if you could post example data for your source dataframes.

Comment: this is how my two dataframes merged look like :

Comment: Client            Ville      Category Qte Montant Date_achat
1      Cl1        Marseille        S7  28    2750 16/05/2015
2      Cl1        Marseille        S7  27    2570 03/06/2015
3      Cl3        Marseille       S14  25    1240 21/11/2015
4      Cl3        Marseille       S14  18    1560 21/10/2016
5      Cl3        Marseille       S14  15    1460 30/11/2016
6      Cl5         Grenoble       S15  30    1980 19/03/2016
7      Cl9        Marseille       S10  22    2030 19/07/2015

Comment: @Nabil, check out [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1) about posting your data with `dput()`.  Edit your post to include it, then delete the comment (because that unformatted data is just noise then).

Comment: but i think it looks more structred the way i copied it than with dput() function.

Comment: It's not about how it looks. We can paste the output of your dput() inside our own R sessions and easily have an example of your data; then we can test your code and give you a good solution. For that, we also need the example of your two original data frames, not the merged one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution.

I used `dplyr::full_join()` to merge df1 and df2, converted the dates to date format with `lubridate` and then used `dplyr::filter()` for year 2015 and categories S7 and S14:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# expected output from author's OP comment
new_dataframe <- read.table(text = "
  Client Ville Category Qte Montant Date_achat
1 Cl1 Marseille S7 28 2750 16/05/2015
2 Cl1 Marseille S7 27 2570 03/06/2015
3 Cl3 Marseille S14 25 1240 21/11/2015
4 Cl3 Marseille S14 18 1560 21/10/2016
5 Cl3 Marseille S14 15 1460 30/11/2016
6 Cl5 Grenoble S15 30 1980 19/03/2016
7 Cl9 Marseille S10 22 2030 19/07/2015",
                            header = T,
                            stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  tbl_df()

# backwardly create df1 df2
df1 <- new_dataframe %>%
  select(Client, Ville, Category) %>%
  unique()

df2 <- new_dataframe %>%
  select(Client, Qte, Montant, Date_achat)

# join data frames
full_join(df1, df2, by = "Client")

# converts date to date format
new_dataframe$Date_achat <- dmy(new_dataframe$Date_achat)

# filtered data frame
df <- new_dataframe %>%
  filter(year(Date_achat) == 2015, (Category == "S7" | Category == "S14"))

# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#   Client Ville     Category   Qte Montant Date_achat
#   <chr>  <chr>     <chr>    <int>   <int> <date>    
# 1 Cl1    Marseille S7          28    2750 2015-05-16
# 2 Cl1    Marseille S7          27    2570 2015-06-03
# 3 Cl3    Marseille S14         25    1240 2015-11-21
```